# What Laplacian should we use for spectral clustering?

Tags: spectral-graph-theory, clustering

The second eigenvector of the normalized Laplacian $I-D^{-1}W$ or the symmetric normalized Laplacian $I-D^{-1/2}WD^{-1/2}$ can be used to approximate a minmizer of the normalized cut problem.

Which one should be used and why ?

Answer (score 1):

The paper "[A tutorial on spectral clustering](http://www.kyb.mpg.de/fileadmin/user_upload/files/publications/attachments/Luxburg07_tutorial_4488%5B0%5D.pdf)"  mentions that (page 27):

> Which normalized Laplacian?
>
> Looking at the differences between the two normalized spectral clustering algorithms using $L_{rw}$ and
>   $L_{sym}$, all three explanations of spectral clustering are in favor of $L_{rw}$. The reason is that the eigenvectors
>   of $L_{rw}$ are cluster indicator vectors $\mathbb{1}_{A_i}$
>   , while the eigenvectors of Lsym are additionally multiplied
>   with $D^{1/2}$
>   , which might lead to undesired artifacts. As using $L_{sym}$ also does not have any computational
>   advantages,
>
> we thus advocate for using $L_{rw}$.

where (page 5):

> L = D - W
>
> $L_{sym}$ := $D^{−1/2}LD^{−1/2}$ = $I − D^{−1/2}W D^{−1/2}$
>
> $L_{rw}$ := $D^{−1}L$ = $I − D^{−1}W$.